# Is this a familiar distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions

I have the following distribution but I am unsure if it is a common distribution. Assume that $\alpha +\beta>0$. I have searched but nothing comes up. Any help would be appreciated!

\begin{equation}
 p(x) = \frac{\sqrt{\beta}}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\frac{\alpha^2}{4 \beta}} e^{-\alpha x-\beta x^2} I_{-\infty,\infty}(x)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a [Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution): just complete the square in the exponent. After doing so, you will find that it is $N(\mu,\sigma)$ where $\mu=-\alpha/2\beta$ and $\sigma=1/\sqrt{2\beta}$ (assuming that $\beta>0$, otherwise your formula doesn't give a probability density).

Comment: I should have seen this. Thank you